# Python get docstring without params

Tags: python

How I can retrieve the docstring from a function without additional params?

```
def foo(user, id):
    """
    Description

    :param user: username
    :param id: id
    :return: bar
    """
    pass
```

For the doc I can use `foo.__doc__` but the string include also `:param:` and `:return:`. How I can get only the function description?

Comment: You can't, it's just one multiline string. You will have to parse it to extract what you want (e.g. ignoring blank lines or those whose first non-whitespace character is `':'`).

Comment: Uhm, regex to drop any line that start with semicolon?

Comment: `re.search(r'\bDescription\b.*?(?=\n\s*:)',foo.__doc__).group()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

You could get the full docstring and then use some regex to remove the params or retrieve only the non-param text. But this is somewhat impossible to do unless you know how the docstring is formated.